# How do I find the code in the 3rd assignment?

Tags: skyfall-bioes

In Sony's viral *Skyfall* game, [British Intelligence Officer Exam Simulation](http://007.com/), I can't work out how to get the code to stop the drone in the third mission. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the agent to listen to the computerised voice in the enemy room. It will give you something in a foreign language that you can use...

Answer (score 0):

Look at a phone keypad. It goes in a circle like this:

```
 789
 456
 123
```

the code is 4-7-8

Comment: Most phone keypads, at least where I am from, have 123 at the top and 789 at the bottom. Number pads on keyboards however are usually laid out as you described. Without knowing the game, I can't tell if this is relevant to your answer or not.